# Updating Variable Properties with Async but without Tuple Just Like UserManager

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to write a custom method that does something similar to what the `CreateAsync(...)` method in [AspNetCore Identity UserManager](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/41751467fe5a4be092a3166b82abef9b606e91d3/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L567) does: save data to the data store and return the original data with updated properties from an `async` method.

For example:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { Username = "Someone", Email = "some@one.com" };

var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssw0rd");
```

In this example, the `user` variable will contain other properties that have been updated after the `CreateAsync(...)` was called.

How does this work when you cannot use `ref` in an `async` method AND they aren't using `Tuple<,>`?

Comment: The methods in `UserManager` are inherited from Identity, which contains many logical relationships. If you want to achieve similar functionality, maybe you need to execute the manual update command. Or you can choose to apply the existing logic in Identity, refer to the link: [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: @Chen thanks. Maybe I am misunderstanding your comment, my question is unrelated to Identity, but rather how does the `CreateAsync` method in Identity update the `user` variable within an `async` call? I thought this was not possible.